# Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{ \frac{n^2}{2}} 2^{n^2-2k}\binom{n^2}{2k} = \frac{3^{n^2}+1}{2}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Question is  for even n>0. I found this to be true, [even wolfram says](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20from%20k%3D0%20to%20n**2%2F2%202**%28n**2-2k%29*%28n**2%29%21%2F%282k%29%21%2F%28n**2-2k%29%21) so, but when I click on show steps it won't.

Question again:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{ \frac{n^2}{2}} 2^{n^2-2k}\binom{n^2}{2k} = \frac{3^{n^2}+1}{2}$$

Comment: Have you thought of replacing $n^2$ by arbitrary $N$ and proving the identity? Where it is very reminiscent of a binomial formula.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: try $\frac{(2+1)^{n^{2}}+(2-1)^{n^{2}}}{2}$